# Can you name those countries on the Schengen visa?

Tags: visa, schengen

I have been issued a Schengen visa which is valid for, A - F - EE - I - LT - LV - MT - PL - SI.

From my understanding:

EE = Estonia
LT = Lithuania
LV= Latvia
MT= Malta
PL= Poland
SI= Slovenia

So what do A, F and I stand for?[image]

Comment: Are you sure A, F and I are separate codes? From this website seems all the codes should be two-lettered http://visainfo.co.in/schengen-visa/schengen-visa-codes

Comment: Also, probably this question is better fit for http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I tried to upload the photo, but I can't!

Comment: There I uploaded the photo!

Comment: Austria, France, Italy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Travel.SE